# remove Image meta data from Image in C#

Tags: c#

I want to remove meta data of image.
You can see the meta data below image property window.

[image: Image meta data]

You can see the Camera Property of Image. I want to remove all that properties throught c# code.

I write some code for converting image to byte and convert Bitmap image.

```
 Bytes[] ImageContent="wdssswwwws"; //Byte array of Image
 MemoryStream ThumbStream = new MemoryStream(ImageContent);
 Bitmap Thumbbitmap = new Bitmap(ThumbStream);
```

How we can remove this meta data from image.

Comment: This is known colloquially as EXIF data. Certain areas of the byte array are demarcated for each set of 100-200 or so properties, as defined in the EXIF standard. JPEG offers the greatest support.

Comment: Have a look at [ExifLibrary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43665/ExifLibrary-for-NET). Or simply Image.Save the images over the old ones.